# Can be convert following java code to Lambda expression?

Tags: lambda, java-8

I need to know following  code can be convert to lamda expression.

```
private class K<D extends BaseDose<I>, I extends DoseInstance>
    implements Predicate<Prescription<D, I>>
  {
    @Override
    public boolean test(final Prescription<D, I> input)
    {
      return DepositType.DATE == input.getBaseDeposit().getDepositType();
    }
  }
```

Comment: `Predicate<Prescription<D, I>>` is a functional interface, so yes. The whole thing can probably be written as `input -> DepositType.DATE == input.getBaseDeposit().getDepositType()`.

Comment: @ernest_k Shouldn't this be an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of creating a class (your `K` class) that implements `Predicate<Prescription<D, I>>`, you can assign a lambda expression to a `Predicate` variable.

For example:

```
Predicate<Prescription<BaseDose<DoseInstance>, DoseInstance>> pred =
    p -> DepositType.DATE == p.getBaseDeposit().getDepositType();
```

If you need a lambda expression with multiple statements, you can write:

```
Predicate<Prescription<BaseDose<DoseInstance>, DoseInstance>> pred =
    p -> {
        final SigningStatus signingStatus = p.getSigningStatus();
        return !p.isReplacedByLatest() && SigningStatus.INVALIDATED.equals(signingStatus);
    };
```

though this can be simplified to a single statement:

```
Predicate<Prescription<BaseDose<DoseInstance>, DoseInstance>> pred =
    p -> !p.isReplacedByLatest() && SigningStatus.INVALIDATED.equals(p.getSigningStatus());
```

Comment: For the OP : `Predicate<Prescription<?>>` should also work if Prescription is bounded with `BaseDose` and `DoseInstance`, which would make sense.

Comment: @Eran 'inside test , like this code ' final SigningStatus signingStatus = input.getSigningStatus();

      return !input.isReplacedByLatest() && SigningStatus.INVALIDATED.equals(signingStatus);can aslo convert to lambda?